# Arrays and pointers are different

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am currently working through K&R to learn C. The authors made an important distinction that pointers and arrays do behave alike, but they are different because a pointer is a variable and can point to different things while an array does not have this ability.

I understand this, but the following code confuses me a little:

```
int len, nlines; 
char *p, line[MAXLINES]; /* Confusing part */
```

I know when you pass an array to a function it decays into a pointer, but here you can declare a character pointer and a character array on the same line even though they are different? Maybe I am confusing myself but this is weird to me. Thanks!

Comment: You can declare multiple things on one line if they all have the same "root" type, e.g. `int w, x, y[5], z(void);` declares two ints, an int array, and a function returning int.  Some people discourage this practice, preferring one identifier per declaration.

Comment: p is a pointer to char.  line is an array of size of  MAXLINES of char.

Comment: A confusing here is that variables can 'modify' the root type. So `char a, *b, **c` will declare a single character `a`, a pointer to a character `b`, and a pointer to a pointer to a character `c`. Similarly, arrays 'modify' the root type when used in a similar declaration style. Consequently, this is why most modern C developers that I've seen recommend the declaration style depicted in [tadman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43334568/510036) as opposed to on a single declarative line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just declaring multiple variables on the same line and is equivalent to this:

```
char *p; // Pointer
char line[MAXLINES]; // Fixed-sized character array
```

They're not related in any way other than their base type and where they were declared in the source code.

Comment: @Thomas This has absolutely nothing to do with `strcpy()`. This is talking about declaring variables.

Comment: Sorry, the editor is not good, so it looks terrible!, these days I'm doing this example, and for the 2 declarations, I then do the string copy, and I found this error:                `#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
   char *p;
   char line[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
   strcpy(p, line);
   return 0;
}
`, I then suddenly found that someone is asking the same question, I found in string cpy, it will cause this error, thx for any reason behind this!

Comment: @Thomas This is purely discussing how to declare variables of different types, not how to prepare a string buffer for a `strcpy()` operation. For that you need to use `strdup()` if you have POSIX on hand, or a combination of `malloc(strlen(src) + 1)` and `strcpy()` to implement a work-alike.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, there is actually not confusing about this. If you look at the line, the `,` in the code is separating `*p` and `lines[MAXLINES]`. Therefore, the user is declaring two different variables.

You can look at this like:

```
char *p; //Pointer due to the asterik (*)
char line[MAXLINES]; //Array because of []
```

The same thing goes for the `int len, nlines;`.

```
int len; //First int var
int nlines; //Second int var
```

We only write the var on a single line just to make it look clean. Other than that, there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score -3):

They are the same in everything 
you can declare a pointer and use it as array

```
int *ptr,arr[10],value=5;
ptr[0]=value;
*(arr)=value;
```

but the difference is the arrays are constant pointers

Comment: That is wrong, a pointer is not an array, `ptr` points to nothing, `value` is not initialized. You invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: oh please i know it's not initialized assume it's any number

Comment: `ptr` is still uninitialized, so `ptr[0]` invokes undefined behaviour. Also arrays and pointer are not "the same in everything" and arrays are not constant pointers.